# Performing jQuery val() against a textbox with html entities

Tags: jquery, html, encoding

I have set up my issue using a simple js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/um788f6q/

```
<input type="text" id="yo">
$("#yo").val('hell&#39;o')
```

Basically I would like to know if there is a way to display an apostrophe rather than the encoded string. I have encoded the values like this on the server to prevent xss attacks, so decoding is not realy a valid option.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Basically I would like to know if there is a way to display an apostrophe rather than the encoded string.

Nothing sane.

The value property deals in text, not HTML.

As a horrible hack you could convert it to text by parsing the HTML and then reading the resulting text node.

```
$("#yo").val($("<div />").html('hell&#39;o').text());
```

… but don't. Solve the real problem instead.

> I have encoded the values like this on the server to prevent xss attacks

Don't do that.

You're inserting the data into JavaScript, not into HTML.

Don't use a defence for HTML when you aren't dealing in HTML. It could leave you vulnerable.

The appropriate way to encode data for inserting into JavaScript is to use a JSON encoder. (Then encode the resulting JSON with entities if you are putting the JSON in an HTML attribute value, or escape any `/` characters if you are putting it in a `<script>` element).

Comment: I appreciate that. The proper way to encode is in the view, and you encode in a relevant way to how the data is being used. I did make that clear to management, and was told their was no time for that. As a work around I then just encoded using antixss encoder in the backend!

Comment: I like the quote from this page: https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-developer-guide/en/latest/preventing_xss/preventing_xss.html#philosophy-and-general-rules `Delay escaping as long as possible, until you can see the actual context and understand the proper escaping that is required for the context. Browsers interpret different contexts such as HTML, URLs, CSS, and Javascript/JSON with different rules, so there are different escaping requirements based on where the data is being used in a page.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var test = 'hell&#39;o';
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(test).text();
$("#yo").val(decoded);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/um788f6q/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrieving the value of a field or an element with `.val()` /  `.text()` or `.html()` and you want to encode it.

You can use `serialize()` and send it in a data ajaxer easily...

and retrieve field name with value (with any few characters) or the whole html form ;)

Example :

```
var text = $("input#my_input").val('Good Music &#x1F3B6;');
console.log(text);
            
var text = $("input#my_input").serialize();
console.log(text);
```

Who returns: Good Music

Answer (score -2):

You can replace $#39; by ' in JS and replace it back on the server side.

```
<input type="text" id="yo">
$("#yo").val('hell&#39;o'.replace('&#39;',"'"))
```

Comment: There are quite a few html entities - I dont really want to replace them all but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -2):

This should help you

```
var tp = 'hell&#39;o';
var new_tp = $('<textarea />').html(tp).text();
$('#yo').val(new_tp);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um788f6q/4/)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  The element is `input type="text"`, but your code is attached to a `textarea` element.

Comment: It works with input as well `var new_tp = $('<input />').html(tp).text();`