# Entity decode in jquery ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a jquery ajax form to add/edit/delete username list in mysql db.
When I retrieve data with special chars from DB I'd like to populate the modal edit form with entity decoded chars...so for example ù wouldn't show as `&ugrave;`

Here you are the code I'm using:

```
$("body").on("click",".edit-user",function(){

    var id = $(this).parent("td").prev("td").prev("td").prev("td").prev("td").text();
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : url + '/ajax_edit/' + id,
        // type: "POST",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="username"]').val(data.username); // Populate edit modal form with retrieved username data

            $('#con-close-modal').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Contributor'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296182/performing-jquery-val-against-a-textbox-with-html-entities

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Following the linked resource I tried to use $'[name="username"]').val(html(data.username).text(); but didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `echo html_entity_decode(json_encode($data));` in server side PHP script.